# im trying to make a fnaf style camera movement but i cant turn left or limit the turning

Tags: c#

i am trying to make a fnaf fan game as a learning project and my camera turning script doesnt work. i am trying to limit the turning to some specific angles but when i add the > and < symbols it doesnt let me turn left, while still not limiting the turning towards the right.

```
{
    public bool hasMouse = false;

    public float maxRotation = 235;
    public float minRotation = 125;

    public float rotationSpeed = 45f;

    private void Update() 
    {
        if (Input.mousePosition.x >= Screen.width - Screen.width / 4)
        {
            if (this.transform.rotation.y < maxRotation)
            {
                transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
        else if (Input.mousePosition.x <= Screen.width - (Screen.width / 4 * 3))
        {
            if (this.transform.rotation.y > minRotation)
            {
                transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to try using Mathf.Clamp which is much better at limiting rotation and controlling rotation. Futher information on the topic can be found at https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html. I suggest including unity in your tags as this could open your answers up to some more detailed help.

Comment: how would i use Mathf.Clamp to limit the rotaton if im using .Rotate? would i need to make some sort of variable?

Comment: Once again, I really suggest including unity as one of your tags, but... To use it in your code you could do it by `transform.rotation.localEulerAngles = new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp(), Mathf.Clamp());` My unity is a little bit rusty but I think this might work, to get this to work for you just enter the rotations you want to limit in the Mathf.Clamps.

Comment: Also your code would work with this simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is already an existing feature built in with unity. In unity the Mathf class is really useful. The `Mathf` class has a feature called `clamp`. [(More documentation here)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html)

However your code could work with a simple fix. Rather than `this.transform.rotation.y`, you need to replace it with `this.transform.localEulerAngles.y`. In unity it stupidly uses a system called quaternions when you use `transform.rotation.y` and it has a very confusing system, it doesn't use angles. However `transform.localEulerAngles.y` does use angles.

In the end your code might look like this:

```
public bool hasMouse = false;

public float maxRotation = 235;
public float minRotation = 125;

public float rotationSpeed = 45f;

private void Update() 
{
    if (Input.mousePosition.x >= Screen.width - Screen.width / 4)
    {
        if (this.transform.localEulerAngles.y < maxRotation)
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
    else if (Input.mousePosition.x <= Screen.width - (Screen.width / 4 * 3))
    {
        if (this.transform.localEulerAngles.y > minRotation)
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this fixed your issue and have a good day!